# $ rails generate devise User #=> Generates migration using change_table instead of create_table? Devise Bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm setting up my **Rails 5** application with **Devise** using the setup instructions found on [Devise's GitHub page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails)...

After following all the instructions up to where I have to generate my User model that did NOT previously exist...

```
# $ rails generate devise MODEL 
$ rails generate devise User # => User did NOT previously exist!
```

The migration file produced uses ***change*_table** as opposed to ***create*_table**...

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    # Why not create_table???
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

After I create my database...

```
$ rails db:create # => Database created successfully
```

And try to migrate using...

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

I get the following error, which makes complete sense - the *users* table does not exist:

```
== 20180201152148 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

The Devise documentation states the following which implies that if MODEL is does not exist, it will be create:

> This will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with
>   the default Devise modules.

Now perhaps the documentation is referring to the MODEL.rb file, but this doesn't seem like it makes sense at all.

I can't find any Devise bugs related to this, but I see bugs related to when MODLE DOES previously exist.

Q. Did I do something wrong or is this a Devise bug?

****UPDATE****
I was able to fix this by simply changing ***change*_table** to ***create*_table**. I also appropriately renamed the migration file from to **add_devise_to_users** to **create_devise_users**, but it seems I shouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've *not* received a confirmation yet as to whether or not this is a [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) bug or something I did; however, this is how *I* dealt with it. I hope it helps anyone else who is confused, or, is having this particular issue:

**How I dealt with this...**

**First**

I changed the following line in my migration file *from...*

```
change_table :users do |t|
```

*to*

```
create_table :users do |t| # => changed 'change_' to 'create_'
```

**Second**

I renamed my migration file *from...*

```
/db/migrate/20180201152148_add_devise_to_users.rb
```

*to* (more appropriately)

```
/db/migrate/20180201152148_create_devise_users.rb
```

**Third**

I ran my migration from the command line...

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

**Done!**

Comment: That really sucks. Still no word from GitHub Issues? Thanks for the workaround though!